# behavior of `symbol-value` in `progv`

Tags: common-lisp, dynamic-variables

Considering the behavior of dynamic and lexical bound variables, I understand the output of `symbol-value` in the following code (dynamically bound variable `a` is shadowed by a lexical bound variable `a` *(that explanation is wrong, see edit below)*):

```
(defvar a 1)
(let ((a 2))
  (list a (symbol-value 'a)))
 ; => (2 2)
```

But when using `progv` to create a similar environment, `symbol-value` gives a different result:

```
(progv '(x) '(1)
  (let ((x 2))
    (list x (symbol-value 'x))))
 ; => (2 1)
```

Why is `(symbol-value 'x)` returning `1` in the second example?

*final edit accompanying the accepted answer:* throughout comments at Rainer Joswig's answer I learnt that `(let ((a 2)) ... )` does not bind a lexical variable, but shadows the value of the former dynamic binding. Also Martin Buchmann pointed out, in a comment, that `symbol-value` ignores lexical variables.

Comment: I think the [documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_5.htm) of `symbol-value` gives you the explanation. `symbol-value` ignores lexical variables if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @MartinBuchmann thank you, this means my understanding (and explanation) of the first example is wrong. (i.e. this means `a` is not shadowed by a *lexical* bound variable `a`, but only the value is shadowed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PROGV` special form creates dynamic bindings, but does not declare the variable to be *special* for enclosed forms.

Thus we need to declare the `LET` binding of the variable `x` to be special:

```
CL-USER 27 > (progv '(x) '(1)
               (let ((x 2))
                 (declare (special x))
                 (list x (symbol-value 'x))))
(2 2)
```

`DEFVAR` OTOH declares its variable to be special. Globally and there is no direct way to undo that declaration.

Comment: But

    `(let ((x 1))
      (declare (special x))
      (let ((x  2))
        (list x (symbol-value 'x))))`
     evals to `; => (2 1)`

Comment: Also I have a problem to distinguish between the meanings of "variable with dynamic binding" and "special variable". Is the explanation at the [c2 wiki](https://wiki.c2.com/?SpecialVariable)? (I've not yet full grasped the meaning of "IndefiniteScope", thats an english translation issue on my side)

Comment: First comment: @jue: The *special* declaration is only for the first LET.

Comment: Second comment: @jue: a variable declared to be *special* binds values in a dynamic environment. They are not *lexical variables*.

Comment: ok, so regarding the examples in my question, `(let ((a 2))...)` does not bind a lexical variable, while `(let ((x 2)) ...)` binds a lexical variable. Is that correct?